# Describing the temperature of a gas in a two-dimensional box

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, statistics

> Find the temperature of a system with fixed energy $E_0$ composed of $N=N_A \times 10^{-5}$ identical particles of mass m free to move in a square box of lenght $L$.

To find the temperature of a system with fixed energy, we can use the microcanonical description. But I am having some trouble figuring out how to find the number of states acessible to the system.
I started by writing the energy of a single particle in the box as:

$$E_i (\vec r , \vec p) = V(\vec r) + \frac{\vec p_i}{2m}$$

Where $V(\vec r)$ is a step function (zero for when the particle is inside the  box and infinite outside). So the number of states has to somehow be linked to the number of combinations of $\vec p_i$ that wield the same total energy when I sum over all states, but how do we express that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done using a Dirac delta when integrating over all the possible values of the momentum

$$\Omega\left(E_{0}\right)=\int\Pi_{i=1}^{N}\dfrac{dp_{ix}dp_{iy}}{h^{2}}dx_idy_i\delta\left(E_{0}-\sum_i E_{i}(\vec{r}_{i},\vec{p}_{i})\right),$$

where $\Omega\left(E_{0}\right)$ is the number of states with energy $E_0$ (I am not completely sure about the normalization factor).

This is the continuum version of the combinations of $\vec{p_i}$ that you mentioned.

Comment: I don't get why the delta function is of $E_0 - E_i$ tho, since $E_0$ is the total energy of the system and $E_i$ is the energy of individual particles... shouldn't it be then $E_0 - \sum E_i$?

Comment: You are right. Just edited.